# In TypeScript can I declare that the current scope contains all the members of an interface?

Tags: typescript

I am using JS as the scripting engine hosted in a product, i.e. I control the global object that scripts see when they execute (the equivalent of `window` in a browser).

As it happens I am also implementing that global object in JS, at least at the top level.

Since the weekend I have become a TypeScript addict and want to declare the global object's API. My ideal would be for the rich set of functions in the API to all be available without prefixing. That is, in the users scripts I want them to be able to say:

```
doThis();
doThat();
```

Instead of:

```
myApi.doThis();
myApi.doThat();
```

It seems like a minor thing but I'm building a domain-specific system and the prefix `myApi.` will be significant noise.

Anyway, in typescript I can declare an interface:

```
interface MyApi {

    doThis(): void;
    doThat(): void;

    // Lots more...
}
```

Then in the implementation side I can declare a class that implements that interface so I know I'm fulfilling the contract, and use an instance of that class as the global object when I execute my user's scripts.

But for the consuming side, how do I declare the fact that the global object implements `MyApi`?

Looking at `lib.d.ts`, it declares `interface Window` with ~100 members, and then it repeats all those ~100 declarations at the global level with the prefix `declare var` or `declare function` added to each.

So I guess either my users will have to type a prefix before every call to my API, or I'll have to mimic `lib.d.ts` and manually remember to duplicate every member of the API in two places (or write my own script to do this!)

Is that correct?

Comment: I'd write a script to build it if you want it to be consistent as there's not a way to expose an interface as the functions need to be `declare`d for them to have global scope.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare them :

```
declare function doThis();
declare function doThat();

// User can simply type: 
doThis();
```

The reason why lib.d.ts adds stuff to IWindow is to allow users to type stuff with `window.` if they want to e.g.:

`window.alert('hey');`

You do not want users to type `window.doThis()` so you can safely ignore that :)

If you want to support `window` you can simply add to IWindow (since interfaces in typescript are open ended) :

```
interface IWindow {
    doThis(): void;
    doThat(): void;
}
```

and then users can do both `window.doThis()` and simply `doThis()`

Comment: Imagine that you are implementing your own version of the browser DOM in TypeScript. It would be very useful to have the interface `Window` so you could write a class that implemented it, and then you would know that your window object was being type-checked to ensure that it satisfied the contract. So that interface is not just to allow users to type `window.` - it is also vital to the type-safety of your system. Your solution is to remove the interface and do away with the window object, but then there is no way to declare that a given chunk of code must implement these ~100 functions.

Comment: First of all any system that takes global scope as part of its api for himself is doing bad design. Imagine yourself trying to run same code in different environments. You would have to assume there is some code that could make your code that you are porting invalid. Even right now there is a vast field of code that could be shared between environments(node.js, web browser, JScript, any app using webrendering engines for stuff). GO WITH PREFIX of sort.

Comment: @user1749204 - maybe you skipped the first sentence of the question: "I am using JS as the scripting engine hosted in a product, i.e. I control the global object that scripts see when they execute."

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your question, you want a give user a way to import your library methods to user's scope.

While lib.d.ts exporting its methods to global (**window**) scope, you want to have flexibility and let user import it to custom scope, for example - scope of user's function.

This can be done in several ways. Most safe of them would be to let user decide when to import your library in current scope.

I can propose such a way to implement it:

```
//TS code sample
module DoLib {

    interface DoApi {
        doThis();
        doThat();
    }

    class MyDoApi implements DoApi {
        doThis(){ console.log("done this") }
        doThat(){ console.log("done that") }
    }

    var myDoApi = new MyDoApi();

    export function use(ctx){
        ctx.doThis = myDoApi.doThis;
        ctx.doThat = myDoApi.doThat;
        //or can just iterate over all methods and add them to ctx
    }
}

//JS CODE : TSC WILL NOT COMPILE
function userCode(){
    DoLib.use(this);
    doThis();
    doThat();
}

userCode();
```

**UPDATE**:

I see that you need not just to export interface of class to specific scope, but typize it for TS scripts. It means that exported scope should be declared as TS file, so TS compiler can check its API.

Lib.d.ts doing similar thing, but in backward order - first, it declares globally typed functions, than declares them again arranged into modules.

Considering that you are exporting functions of your API to global scope, declaration would look like:

```
declare function doThis(p:number);
declare function doThat(s:string);
```

This declarations refer to JS context, not TS context.

In case if TS whoule be runtime-language, like JS is, you woule be able to use reflecation and evaluate those copy-paste declarations on-fly using declarations from your interface API.

But it is not. And you have either to do it manually, or use some kind of meta-compiler or preprocessor to do this declarations. I can suggest you to use direct includes using some kind on file composition engine. This would allow you to do it in such a way:

**/* DoApi.d.ts */**

```
//Declare to global scope
declare function doThis(p:number);
declare function doThat(s:string);
```

**/* DoApi.ts */**

```
module DoLib {

    export interface DoApi {
       <% inject DoApi.d.ts %>
    }

    export class MyDoApi implements DoApi {
        doThis(n:number){ console.log("done this") }
        doThat(s:string){ console.log("done that") }
    }

    export var myDoApi = new MyDoApi();

    export function use(ctx){
        ctx.doThis = myDoApi.doThis;
        ctx.doThat = myDoApi.doThat;
    }
}
```

**/* User.js */**

```
//your global object
var globalObject = window;

//userCode
DoLib.use(globalObject);
doThis(1);
doThat("s");
```

Comment: Do I need to clarify my question? The idea is that the API is declared in TypeScript so both sides (implementation and users) can benefit from type safety. Obviously if the user code is in JavaScript then the problem goes away!

Comment: Thanks, that helped to understand your idea better. A solution would be to typize global object and use global "import" of your module API, but thats not supported in TS, probably because this was thought as potential source of namespace mess. I've updated an answer with a practical solution, similar to what WiredPrairie suggested.